# Is there any well-known British accent which aʊ is pronounced like əʊ in?

Tags: pronunciation, accent, british-english

I think I've heard the word "about" pronounced with əʊ (as in "Poland"). Is it just me or there's indeed such an accent in Great Britain or, more specifically, in England?

Comment: Possibly the West Country accent. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Country_English#Phonology

Comment: "About pronounced əʊ, as in Poland"? That reminds me of "Thomson without a P, as in Venezuela"!

Comment: "Aboot" (for "about") is a common theatrical Britishism.  I've rarely if ever encountered it in real life, though.